# Storm Supervisor daemon dies: No space left on device exception

Tags: java, exception, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am running a storm cluster on a single node i.e. nimbus, supervisor all are running on the same node in distributed mode. The topology ran for 7 days wthout any problem but suddenly the supervisor daemon died. There is no supervisor.log file present and on checking the worker logs I found the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:325) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(FileUtils.java:2095) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(FileUtils.java:2078) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.persist(LocalState.java:102) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.put(LocalState.java:82) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$do_heartbeat.invoke(worker.clj:69) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
```

I have searched already for this exception but I am unable to understand why did it occur. I have sufficient space available on my system. And I have doubt that can a supervisor die because of some worker ? In my setup I am using **storm.local.dir:** as **/mnt/storm**.

Also what is the use of LocalState.java when we already have a zookeeper ? 
I found some discussion on storm-user at this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/Q7-sM42gWi0.

But in that discussion they have been running storm in local mode and Nathan Marz has provided explanation for the same. But in my case it is distributed mode. Please ask for more information if needed. Thanks

Comment: Do you write to local disk in the topology? Did log files get rotated freeing up the space? Is your disk partitioned? You were out of space at the time the error happened, but if you are not out of space now then something was cleaned up after the error happened.

Comment: Yes I have the same first impression of this error. Then again the question arises that how do we clean up the log files automatically. Is there any setting for that in storm ??

Comment: well, you would use something like logrotate to deal with the logs. There is nothing built into storm AFAIK.